# Using awk to extract lines between patterns

Tags: awk

I am trying to use awk to extract lines between two patterns, but as the second pattern involves multiple `$$$$` sign I do not manage to protect properly the `$`

input is:

```
Name1
iii
iii
$$$$

Name2
ii
ooo
ppp
$$$$

Name3
pp
oo
ii
uu
$$$$
```

desired output

```
Name2
ii
ooo
ppp
$$$$
```

I tried something like this:

```
awk 'BEGIN {RS="\\$\\$\\$\\$\n"; FS="\n"} $1==Name2 {print $0; print "$$$$"}' inputfile
```

I also tried something like

```
awk '/^Name2/,/\\$\\$\\$\\$\\/' input
```

I tried many different protection of $ but i do it wrong, either nothing is printed or it prints the entire file

Many thanks for suggestions

Comment: I put a return after each $$$$ and tried something like     awk 'BEGIN {RS="\\$\\$\\$\\$\n"; FS="\n"} $1==Name2 {print $0; print "$$$$"}'

Comment: can you add your code to the question?

Comment: what is the actual output of that code?

Comment: With GNU grep: `grep -Poz '^Name2(\n.*?)*\$\$\$\$' file`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to select lines between two patterns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38972736/how-to-select-lines-between-two-patterns)

Answer (score 2):

you don't have to use patterns if you're looking for a literal match

```
awk '$0=="Name2",$0=="$$$$"' file
```

will extract the lines between the two literals.  Or a combination if the first match is a pattern

```
awk '/Name2/,$0=="$$$$"' file
```

Comment: Interesting! Never knew that

Comment: s/pattern/regexp/g. patterns are for quilts and sweaters.

Answer (score 1):

**`Awk`** solution:

```
awk '/^Name2/{ f=1 }f; $1=="$$$$"{ f=0 }' file
```

- `f` variable is a marker indicating the possibility for the current line to be printed

The output:

```
Name2
ii
ooo
ppp
$$$$
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using `$$$$` as the record separator, you may use the double empty lines, meaning splitting into *paragraphs*:

```
awk 'BEGIN{RS=""}/Name2/' file
```

`RS=""` is a special value. From the `awk` man page:

> If RS is set to the null string, then records are separated by blank lines.  When RS is set to the null string, the newline character always acts as
>          a field separator, in addition to whatever value FS may have.

---

While the above code is fine for your example, you get into troubles when there are keys like `Name20`. Meaning a regex match might not be the right approach. An string comparison would probably be a better suite:

```
awk 'BEGIN{RS="";FS="\n"} $1 == "Name2"' file
```

I'm explicitly setting `FS="\n"` to avoid splitting within single lines.

Comment: The is the right approach but I'd use `RS=""; FS="\n"; ... $1=="Name2"` for robustness.

Comment: Nice to hear that! :) It took me a moment, but I get your point about explicitly setting `FS="\n"`. I was actually under the impression that FS is the newline, but true is that the newline will be added to FS. Anyhow, since I'm using `/Name2/` and not `$1=="Name2"` it should be ok. Isn't it? But I admit that, depending on the use case, the latter might be the better solution. It really depends.

Comment: The problem with `/Name2/` vs `$1=="Name2"` is that because the former is doing a partial regexp match across the whole record instead of an exact string match on a specific field like the latter is doing, the former will falsely match if/when the text "Name2" appears in various other contexts. As a very probable example - what if a record started with `Name20`? Also consider `I hate that guy Name2` appearing in one of the records for `Name3`, etc.

Comment: Many thanks for your explanation! Now it sounds simple. Man! name20, how could I overlook that... Let me change the post tomorrow, it's late here.